# jQuery `.focus()` not working

Tags: jquery, html, input, focus

Here is my simple code, but it does not seem to work.
I have read many Q&A's but I don't know what I have done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function focus(){
            $("#input").focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="focus();">button</button>
    <input id="input">
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure there is something I am missing but I don't know what it is, I would like any help in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename you focus function, it is conflicting with the jquery in-built function `focus()`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function focus1(){
            $("#input").focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="focus1();">button</button>
    <input id="input">
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qb84qozy/1/)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is function name.change focus to any other name which doesn't exists in library.in jquery library there is function named as focus and you declare function name as focus too.

```
function myFunc(){
        $("#input").focus();
}

 <button onClick="myFunc();">button</button>
```

look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/onq2jgjo/

Comment: thanks for your reply, im not trying to name change anything, im trying to get the text cursor to appear in the input when button is click

Comment: Serlkhan is saying the same please try to understand his answer.

Comment: okay, thanks, now understood by reading the answer below, thanks guys, this has been doing my head in